# Uniformly continuous at two intervals

Tags: calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

If I have function $f$ which is uniformly continuous at interval $[a,b)$ and at interval $[b, c)$ as well, can I conclude that $f$ is uniformly continuous at $[a, c)$?

I am pretty sure that this argue is true, but I can't find a proper proof.
What I though about was taking the minimum value of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ (which are the working deltas for $[a,b)$ and $[b, c)$) and say that for that delta the function if uniformly continuous at the whole interval.
However, I do not manage to prove it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not necessarily true. Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x< 1\\ 1 & x\geq 1\\\end{cases}.$$ If $a=0$, $b=1$, and $c=2$, we can conclude that $f$ is uniformly continuous of $[a,b)$ and $[b,c)$, but not on $[a,c)$. However, the idea you have of taking the minimum of two $\delta$ values is a good one. If you insist that $f$ also be continuous at $b$, the method you are thinking of will work. It goes like this:

Suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b)$ and $[b,c)$ and is continuous at $b$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ which satisfy the definition of uniform continuity in $[a,b)$ and $[b,c)$ respectively. There also exists a $\delta_3$ such that if $|x-b|<\delta_3$, then $|f(x)-f(b)|<\varepsilon/2$. Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3\}.$ Choose $x,y\in [a,c)$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$. Without loss of generality, assume $x<y$. Clearly, if $x,y\in [a,b)$, then $|x-y|<\delta\leq\delta_1$, so $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. Similarly if $x,y\in [b,c)$. If $a\leq x<b<y<c$, Then $|x-b|<|x-y|<\delta\leq\delta_3$, so $|f(x)-f(b)|<\varepsilon/2$. Similarly, $|f(b)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/2$. Thus, $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(b)|+|f(b)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2<\varepsilon.$$ So we see that in all cases, $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$, so $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,c)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 1) Why is your example function is not uniformly continuous at [a,c)? 2) if function $f$ is uniformly continuous at [b, c) it should be continuous at b by definition - isn't it true?

Comment: 1) The function is not uniformly continuous on $[a,c)$ because if $\epsilon<1$, there is no $\delta$ which satisfies the definition of uniform continuity if $x>1$ and $y<1$. 2) Go back to the definition of uniform continuity on an interval $[b,c)$. It implies continuity on the interior of the interval, but not at the endpoints.

Comment: To clarify for (2), I mean that the definition of uniform continuity implies continuity *with respect to the whole real line* on the interior of the interval, and not on the endpoints.

Comment: So however, how can I find the delta I need, assuming that $f$ is also continuous at $b$? how can I prove by definition that taking the minimum of the two deltas will work?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a proof of uniform continuity given that $f$ is continuous at $b$.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't even say it is continuous, unless $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=f(b)$ (observe that the limit exists because $f$ is uniformly continuous.) If the previous equality holds, then the answer is yes. To control $|f(x)-f(y)|$ you will need $\delta_1$ when $x,y\in[a,b)$, $\delta_2$ when $x,y\in[b,c)$ and $\delta_3$ when $x<b\le y$.

Comment: And how can I find that $\delta_3$? is it the minimum value as I said? or is there other method to find it?

Comment: If the condition is satisfied $f$ s continuous at $b$. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta_3$ so that $x<b\le y$ and $y-x<\delta_3\implies|f(x)-f(y)|\le\epsilon$. Now choose $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3)$.